# Navigation Bar not appearing when presenting View?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationbar

The navigation bar do not appear, when choose this line of code

```
  self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But when tried this code

```
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "view")
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

My app crashes, giving an error

```
NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller
```

Please help me to get navigation bar when presenting a view and not pushing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing this -

```
self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Happy to help you @cole, anyways that was just a small mistake.

Comment: Yup, I see that now.